# I am working on a heroku api with a postgresql database that stores books but I can't get it to work on the front-end

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, api, heroku

I have successfully created an api that stores books on heroku with express and postgresql following this tutorial https://www.taniarascia.com/node-express-postgresql-heroku/ witch everything works fine but I tried to follow the front-end part but it doesn't work.

Here is the api here https://node-api-with-books.herokuapp.com/books

Any help would be appreciated and it would help me if you used the tutorial to help.

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the tutorial you would need an async function to call the api from a front end.

```
async function getBooks() {
  try {
     const response = await fetch("https://node-api-with-books.herokuapp.com/books");
    return await response.json();
    // console.log(books)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error", error);
  }
}

getBooks().then(book => {
   console.log(book);
});
```

Check the console in Stackblitz - https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-9dmngb?file=index.js

Comment: That works great thanks! I guess the tutorial just doesn't specify that you need to use a function and I should have figured it out!